# Is this passive voice misuse?

Tags: passive-voice, software-bugs

What is wrong with this? I have quintupple checked it, but grammarly tells me that I have passive voice misuse. Can someone help?

> "The Japanese were warned that one of their cities, Hiroshima, which is also where their 2nd army was, would vanish."

Comment: It looks OK to my (admittedly) inexpert eyes. Don't trust automatic grammar checkers. Even better, don't use them.

Comment: Yes, you're using a passive. If Grammarly doesn't like it, stop using Grammarly.

Comment: Trust me those grammar checkers are useless.

Comment: +1 to what others have said about not paying much (if any) attention to grammar checkers. And yes, "The Japanese were warned" is passive voice. "The Americans warned the Japanese" is not passive voice.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. However *quintuple* only has one "p". Moreover it is the adverb you need, not the adjective, so I think you should say  "I have quintuply checked it". (The OED concurs)

Comment: For a better wording of the sentence, I suggest: The Japanese were warned that one of their cities, Hiroshima (where their Second Army was), would vanish. Or: The Japanese were warned that Hiroshima, the location of their Second Army, would vanish. (As for the second sentence, I removed "one of their cities" because the phrase may not be needed--unless your readers do not know that Hiroshima is a city in Japan.

Comment: I think there's a tense problem? Should "which *is* also where their 2nd army *was*" by "which *was* also where their 2nd army *was*". Not the best phrasing, either way.

Answer (score 8):

Ignore it. This is the outcome of rule creep: gradually escalating sound syntactical advice into a senseless grammatical "rule".

Level 1: Overuse of the passive can definitely be a stylistic vice (yes, that's *vice*, not *device*).

Level 2: Overuse of the passive is frequent enough that many teachers and writers on style find it necessary to issue stern warnings against it.

Level 3: Insensitive writers on style have been known to elevate such warnings against overuse of the passive to deprecation of *any* use of the passive.

Level 4: Incompetent editors and grammar checkers mechanically mark every use of the passive as an 'error'.

Comment: Well, at least it was in the passive. Half the time when an incompetent editor complains about passive it isn't even an example of it.

Comment: @JonHanna Been reading [Pullum 2009](http://www.chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497) again?! It's good to visit in midwinter: always cheers me up.

Answer (score 3):

Use of the passive in English varies with writing style and field. Some publications' style sheets discourage use of the passive voice, while others encourage it.  If you are discouraged from using the passive voice then you need to pay attention to grammar checkers such as Grammarly.

When looking at passive voice there is an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice) where

> "Caesar was stabbed by Brutus" is in the passive voice. The subject, **Caesar**, indicates the person acted upon. The agent is expressed here with the phrase **by Brutus**, but this can be omitted. The equivalent sentence in the active voice is "Brutus stabbed Caesar", in which the subject denotes the doer, or agent, Brutus.

So the sentence you have is in the passive voice as the subject is the Japanese who were warned.  To change to an active (non-passive) voice you need to add who gave the warning and rearrange the first part of the sentence.  If it was the Chinese who warned the Japanese, you could say

> The Chinese warned the Japanese that one of their cities.....